# Unable to update user password using Appwrite PHP SDK

Tags: php, authentication, nosql, appwrite

The Appwrite PHP SDK is helping me update a user's password, but I am having trouble with it. The code I am using is this one:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Appwrite\Client;
use Appwrite\Services\Users;
use Appwrite\Services\ServiceException;

$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$getUserByid = getUserByid($user_id);
$appwrite_id = $getUserByid['appwrite_id'];

$client = new Client();
$client
    ->setEndpoint('Your API Endpoint') 
    ->setProject('Your project ID') 
    ->setKey('Your secret API key'); 

$users = new Users($client);

try {
    $response = $users->updatePassword($appwrite_id, $password);
    var_dump($response);
} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    echo 'Error updating user password: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

However, when I check the user's information in the Appwrite console, the password field remains empty.
[image]

I have also tried creating user with their encrypted password code:

```
$result = $users->createMD5User('[USER_ID]', 'email@example.com', 'password');
```

The Appwrite console's password field is left empty in both scenarios. Could you please check if there is a problem with the Appwrite PHP SDK or what I might be doing incorrectly?

I have read through their documentation (https://appwrite.io/docs/server/users?sdk=php) regarding related code. ),
and tried all of their updated password codes and encrypted password user codes, but every time I tried, the same thing happened!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized my error; my code was actually operating correctly, but user passwords are hashed and not visible in the console for security and privacy reasons.